# Adding menu item on both top bar and bottom bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my code I want to display some menu item on top action bar and some on
bottom bar.I tried using split action bar,but when I used split action bar,
all menu item set to bottom bar.
so how can I display some menu item on top bar and some on bottom bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    View view = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.actionbar,
            null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(view);

}
```

and then for the bottom bar I inflated my menu view or whatever you want to appear at bottom-

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.browser_main, menu);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(
            R.id.layout_item).getActionView();

    View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.media_bottombar, null);

    relativeLayout.addView(inflatedView);

    return true;
}
```

Android Manifest-

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `android:showAsAction="never|withText"` in your menu item which you want to show in bottom.

Never add `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in manifest if you want simple bottom menu, it just helps to create or add the bottom menubar.